# Fastest opening goal of a FIFA World Cup

Tags: football, trivia, history, records, world-cup

**What was the fastest opening goal of a FIFA World Cup?**

This is not the fastest opening goal in a single match across tournaments, but fastest goal(the first goal of that particular World edition) of the tournament as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having looked through Wikipedia, I can find two goals which were scored in the 4th minute of one of a number of simultaneous opening matches:

- In 1934, [all eight first round matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1934_FIFA_World_Cup#First_round) kicked off simultaneously. [Ernesto Belis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernesto_Belis) scored in the 4th minute of the Sweden vs Argentina match.
- In 1962, the first match in each of the four groups kicked off simultaneously. [Héctor Facundo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9ctor_Facundo) scored in the 4th minute of the [Argentina vs Bulgaria match in Group 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_4).

Given the age of particularly the first of those goals, I suspect we'll never know which was scored earlier in the match.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an answer listing times of first goals in FIFA World Cups. It is community wiki, feel free to edit it - correct mistakes, add more sources, etc.

2022: [Valencia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enner_Valencia) 16'
2018: [Gazinsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yury_Gazinsky) 12'
2014: [Marcelo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcelo_(footballer,_born_1988)) (own goal) 11'
2010: [Tshabalala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphiwe_Tshabalala) 55'
2006: [Lahm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philipp_Lahm) 6'
2002: [Diop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papa_Bouba_Diop) 30' 
1998: [César Sampaio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Sampaio) 5' (or 4' according to some sources)
1994: [Klinsmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%BCrgen_Klinsmann) 61'
1990: [Omam-Biyik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Omam-Biyik) 67'
1986: [Altobelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alessandro_Altobelli) 43'
1982: [Vandenbergh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Vandenbergh) 62'
1978: [Rossi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paolo_Rossi) 29'<sup>1</sup>
1974: [Breitner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Breitner) 18'<sup>1</sup>
1970: [Dermendzhiev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinko_Dermendzhiev) 13' <sup>1</sup>
1966: [Pelé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pel%C3%A9) 15', [Held](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigfried_Held) 15' <sup>1</sup>
1962: [Facundo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9ctor_Facundo) 4'<sup>3</sup>
1958: [Simonsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agne_Simonsson) 17'
1954: [Milutinovic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milo%C5%A1_Milutinovi%C4%87) 15'<sup>3</sup>
1950: [Ademir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ademir_Marques_de_Menezes) 30'
1938: [Gauchel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Gauchel) 29'
1934: [Belis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernesto_Belis) 4'<sup>3</sup>
1930: [Laurent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucien_Laurent) 19'<sup>3</sup>

<sup>1</sup>The first match of the tournament was a goalless draw, this goal is not from the opening match.
<sup>2</sup>The first two matches of the tournament were goalless draws.
<sup>3</sup> Several matches started at the same time (so there was really no opening match of the tournament).

---

**Sources:**

general: Wikipedia article [List of FIFA World Cup opening matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_opening_matches), [1](https://books.google.com/books?id=OkSTxbAwc3YC), [2](https://books.google.sk/books?id=FdpMrBfmEJQC), [3](https://books.google.sk/books?id=4uJdBgAAQBAJ)
2022 Wikipedia - [2022 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup), [Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_statistics), [Group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage), [Group A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A)
2018 Wikipedia - [2018 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup), [Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_statistics), [Group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage), [Group A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A)
2014 Wikipedia - [2014 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [Group A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_group_stage#Group_A), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/2014brazil/match-center/300186456), [2](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-soccer-world-m1-bra-cro-owngoal-idUSKBN0EN2E520140613)
2010 Wikipedia - [2010 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup), [Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_statistics), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [Group A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/2010south-africa/match-center/300061454), [2](http://www.uefa.com/news/newsid=1497143.html)
2006 Wikipedia - [2006 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup), [Group A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/2006germany/match-center/97410001), [2](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2006/jun/17/worldcup2006.sport2), [3](http://www.uefa.com/teamsandplayers/players/player=63033/profile/), [4](https://books.google.com/books?id=FdpMrBfmEJQC&pg=PA506)
2002 Wikipedia - [2002 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup), [Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_statistics), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [Group A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A), [1](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/round=43950100/match=43950001/index.html#nosticky), [2](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/worldcup2014/article-2656049/World-Cup-opening-matches-From-Brazils-win-against-Scotland-Siphiwe-Tshabalala-screamer-versus-Mexico.html)
1998 Wikipedia - [1998 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [Group A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1998france/match-center/4000), [2](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/y=1998/m=6/news=fastest-goal-award-cesar-sampaio-still-unbeaten-71690.html)/[2a](http://web.archive.org/web/20170123202519/https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/y=1998/m=6/news=fastest-goal-award-cesar-sampaio-still-unbeaten-71690.html) (this source says it was scored at 3:48), [3](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/videos/y=2014/m=6/video=1998-fifa-world-cuptm-sampaio-s-goal-against-scotland-2363457.html)/[3a](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101110706/http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/videos/y=2014/m=6/video=1998-fifa-world-cuptm-sampaio-s-goal-against-scotland-2363457.html)
1994 Wikipedia - [1994 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [Group C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_C), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1994usa/match-center/3049)
1990 Wikipedia - [1990 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_FIFA_World_Cup), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_FIFA_World_Cup#Statistics), [Group B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_B), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1990italy/match-center/26), [2](http://www.the42.ie/cult-world-cup-teams-cameroon-1990-2115922-Jun2014/)
1986 Wikipedia - [1986 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_FIFA_World_Cup), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [Group A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1986mexico/match-center/459)
1982 Wikipedia - [1982 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [Group 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_3), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1982spain/match-center/749)
1978 Wikipedia - [1978 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_FIFA_World_Cup), [Group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage), [Group 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_1), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1978argentina/match-center/2347)
1974 Wikipedia - [1974 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974_FIFA_World_Cup), [Group 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_1), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1974germany/match-center/2003)
1970 Wikipedia - [1970 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_FIFA_World_Cup), [Results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_FIFA_World_Cup#Results), [Group 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_4), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1970mexico/match-center/1780)
1966 Wikipedia - [1966 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_FIFA_World_Cup), [Group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1966england/match-center/1656), [2](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1966england/match-center/1596)
1962 Wikipedia - [1962 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_FIFA_World_Cup), [Group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage), [1](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/chile1962/matches/index.html)
1958 Wikipedia - [1958 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_FIFA_World_Cup), [Group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1958sweden/match-center/1415)
1954 Wikipedia - [1954 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_FIFA_World_Cup), [Group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1954switzerland/match-center/1276)
1950 Wikipedia - [1950 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_FIFA_World_Cup), [Group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1950brazil/match-center/1187)
1938 Wikipedia - [1938 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1938_FIFA_World_Cup), [Final tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1938_FIFA_World_Cup#Final_tournament), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1938france/match-center/1165)
1934 Wikipedia - [1934 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1934_FIFA_World_Cup), [Final tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1934_FIFA_World_Cup#Final_tournament), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1934italy/match-center/1102)
1930 Wikipedia - [1930 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1930_FIFA_World_Cup), [Group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1930_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage), [Group 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1930_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_1), [1](https://www.fifa.com/tournaments/mens/worldcup/1930uruguay/match-center/1096), [2](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/y=2010/m=6/news=raiders-the-first-goal-1233723.html)